# What's the different between oauth2Login and oauth2Client? what are the use-case of them?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have seen the Spring security docs.https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2 But I don't really know the different use-case between oauth2Login() and oauth2Client(). Are there any samples ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`oauth2Login()` will authenticate the user with OAuth2 (or OIDC), populating Spring's Principal with the information from either the JWT or the userInfo endpoint. `oauth2Client()` won't authenticate the user but will seek permission from the OAuth2 authorization server for the resources (scopes) it needs to access. With `oauth2Client()` you'll still need to authenticate the user, for example via `formLogin()`.

A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2).

Answer (score -1):

Spring Security provides modules for both the OAuth 2.0 client (application trying to access resources) and the OAuth 2.0 user (resource owner). The OAuth2Client module deals with client-related functionality, while the OAuth2Login module handles user authentication and user-related functionality.

**OAuth2Client**

The OAuth 2.0 client (application) uses the OAuth2Client module to interact with the authorization server, obtain access tokens, and make secure requests to resource servers.

**OAuth2Login**

The OAuth2Login module handles the user authentication process, allowing the user to log in and authorize the client application to access their resources.